# Write to csv from modified csv files with python code

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to process data(remove hastag, link and @) from CSV files and stored it back to CSV. however the output does not perform well. it is separated with a comma for each character. Can anyone help me to write it to csv in a better way. thank you

```
import re,string
import csv

def strip_links(text):
    link_regex    = re.compile('((https?):((//)|(\\\\))+([\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&](#!)?)*)', re.DOTALL)
    links         = re.findall(link_regex, text)
    for link in links:
        text = text.replace(link[0], ', ')    
    return text

def strip_all_entities(text):
    entity_prefixes = ['@','#']
    for separator in  string.punctuation:
        if separator not in entity_prefixes :
            text = text.replace(separator,' ')
    words = []
    for word in text.split():
        word = word.strip()
        if word:
            if word[0] not in entity_prefixes:
                words.append(word)
    return ' '.join(words)

f = open('Test.csv')
csf_f = csv.reader(f)

temp =[]
for row in csf_f:
    temp.append(row[0])

temp1 = []
for t in temp:
    temp1.append(strip_all_entities(strip_links(t)))

for i in range(0, len(temp1)):    

with open('MYOUTPUT.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(temp1)

f.close()
```

Comment: Do you know the full form of csv?

Comment: yes. it consists of text in 6 row. I used sample data and  named it as Test.csv

Comment: look default separation in a CSV is a comma, CSV stands for '**C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues'

Comment: sorry,  I see it from excel so, it looks like there are 6 rows

Comment: You can open csv file with Excel or any spreadsheet program, and it should load properly. If it doesn't, tell me.

Comment: yes I can open it. However the structure of CSV files does not well. it separated by a comma for each character.

Comment: can you show the sample of your MYOUTPUT.csv in your question

Comment: here is 2 row sample of the output.

R,T, ,P,e,m,p,r,o,v,
P,a,p,u,a, ,a,d,a,l,a,h,

i expect it should be like this
RT Pemprov,
Papua adalah,